# CiviContribute PayPal return url problem

Tags: civicontribute, paypal, ipn

Re: PayPal Standard

When we make a donation, the process proceeds normally through the PayPal screens until returning back to our website where we get this message:

"You do not have permission to access this content."

I noticed that the url for the page has this query string added:

"?page=CiviCRM"

I'm guessing extern/ipn.php is adding that query string.  The error happens whether a user is logged in or not, even with admin permissions.

If I removed the query string, of course I get to the original donation page w/ no error message.  I checked permissions; profile views are allowed for all roles, however profile listings are not.  The permission "CiviContribute: make online contributions" is also checked for each role.

On a possibly related note, the payments are not being marked as complete in Civi even though they show complete in both accounts in PayPal.  I made sure I had a complete resource url w/ http://, but this has not helped.

Any help or clues appreciated.

Comment: PS I also tried the new URL http://example.com/civicrm/payment/ipn/x, where x is the payment processor id -- no help

Comment: Interesting...from the log:  /wp-login.php?redirect_to=http://example.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/payment/ipn/2&&reauth=1

It shows ipn/2 even though in the PayPal IPN page, I've entered ipn/1